# "Dynamic" image sometimes resizes to zero - MaterializeCSS Carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I am trying to make a Carousel work from the MaterializeCSS website: http://materializecss.com/carousel.html

My problem is that when I use a "dynamic" image, it will sometimes be resized to 0x0 pixels, although it can see the images "normal" size in the HTML elements inspect - see image #1 below. 
I'm unsure if the problem is caused by some caching error that may occur, or something completely different

The main issue is that it SOMETIMES works. I can refresh the page 10 times, and 2-3 out of the refreshed times it will show the working carousel, but the other times it will show nothing.

If I load an image from an outside source, that will ALWAYS work, even when the local images do not show up.

Please be aware this is just "test" code, so it might be a little messy or have redundant things included, I have just used countless hours trying to find a solution, and have yet to stumble upon one.

(P.S I am using React)

```
render() {

   let items = this.props.images.map((imagePath) => {
      return (
         <a className="carousel-item"><img src={"/images/" + imagePath}/></a>
      )
   })

   return (

      <div className="carousel">
         <a className="carousel-item"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/c/e/P/p/d/d/bullet-1-red-1-hi.png"/></a>
         {items}
      </div>

   )
}
```

From the above code, the "static" example will always work, but the "{items}" part will only sometimes show up.

The error can be seen here in the HTML code.
[image: Zero Picture Size]

After refreshing a couple times it will work once. [image: Working Example]

No code changed between the taking of the two pictures.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to see where the problem might be based on the code you provided. Some suggestions though:

 * Create `items` on `componentDidUpdate` or `componentWillReceiveProps`.
 * Look at the styles tab in the Chrome dev tools Elements pane; what styles are being applied and where are they coming from?

Seems like the issue might come from the styles applied by materializecss.

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much! I do see a difference, sometimes the style will not be applied to the carousel-item.

Not applied:
https://puu.sh/ydvjk/c01c18d16f.png

Applied
https://puu.sh/ydvio/8f0f7c6ee3.png

But this behaviour is rather erratic, as stated, 2-3 times it will load out of 10. Do you have any experience in this field as to why it would behave this way?

Comment: Are you using the materializecss library you linked to, or one of the "reactified" wrappers? Are you initializing the carousel after the images have rendered (i.e. in `componentDidMount`)? Clearly, there is a race condition.

Comment: I'm using the materializecss library, no wrappers.
I've tried componentDidMount, but to no avail.

Also to initialize it, I use:

https://pastebin.com/raw/FLGnCnBb

Comment: Remove `$(document).ready`, you don't need this inside `componentDidMount`. Also read through https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html#integrating-with-jquery-chosen-plugin. It gives an example with a different jQuery library but the ideas will apply to your case.

Comment: Not completely sure what I'm supposed to take from the link you sent me, although I did remove the document ready part. jQuery itself works, I'm just not sure how to fix the race-condition :/

Comment: Can you post a link to a github repo with your code? I can pull it down and see what I can do locally.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too, not in `react` but in `javascript`. To solve it you just have to destroy the `carousel` object after the render of the elements and then start it again. In `javascript`, it would be something like this:

```
$('.carousel').append('<a className="carousel-item"><img src={"/images/" + imagePath}/></a>');
$('.carousel').carousel('destroy');
$('.carousel').carousel();
```